# Differences between executable files generated by Dymola and OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am considering to use the executable file generated by either Dymola (*dymosim.exe*) or OpenModelica (*model_name.exe*) to make parametric simulations on the same model.
I was wondering, is there any difference in the two *.exe* files and related input files? (which are *dsin.txt* for Dymola, and *model_name_init.xml* for OpenModelica).

Regarding file sizes, I can see that the Dymola files are smaller. But I was also wondering about speed of execution and flexibility of the input files for scripting.
Lastly, since Dymola is a commercial software, is the dymosim.exe file publicly shareable?

Comment: Did you consider using FMI (http://fmi-standard.org/)? This would give you a clean interface definition and quite a good starting base e.g. with FMPy (https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy).

Comment: It came up in my mind, but I thought about the .exe file mainly because of two reasons: 1) I am not very familiar with FMI, and 2) The actual parametric process is supposed to run behind the scenes, as I already have a sort of GUI. I could still use the FMI approach, but then the question is: what are the advantages? If I understand correctly, one advantage of the FMI approach could be related to the fact that it will be easier to implement the process in different operating systems (Windows, macOS and Linux)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will write this for OpenModelica, the Dymola people can add their own.

I would suggest to use FMUs instead of executables and some (co)simulation framework like OMSimulator (via Python scripting) or some other ones (PyFMI, etc). See an example here:
https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OMSimulator/master/html/OMSimulatorPython.html#example-pi

Note that if you have resources such as tables, etc, these will be put inside the FMU if you use Modelica URIs: `modelica://LibraryName/Resource/blah`. However, for the generated executables you would need to ship them with the exe and they would need to be in a specific directory on the other machine. Also, you would need to ship dependent DLLs for the executables for the the FMUs that is (mostly - not true if you have external dlls that you call in your model) not needed as they are statically compiled.

Simulation speed depends on the model sometimes one or the other is faster.

For what libraries are supported by OpenModelica you can check the library coverage:
https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/overview-combined.html

If you still want to use executables, here is a list of command line parameters for them: https://www.openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/simulationflags.html

How to do parameter sweeps via executables:
https://openmodelica.org/doc/OpenModelicaUsersGuide/latest/scripting_api.html#simulation-parameter-sweep

Comment: Just to be sure that I understood. Basically, if I export an FMU with OpenModelica and then distribute it to others, will these people be able to simulate the FMU using PyFMI?

Comment: Yes, or any other FMI based simulation tool.

Comment: Regarding the .exe approach: I just had a closer look at the model_name_init.xml file, and I can see that line 10 (at least in my file) says "OPENMODELICAHOME" and it seems pointing to a path related to the installation of OpenModelica. Also, there are several "fileName" lines pointing to paths where the modelica models (.mo files) used for simulation are stored. Does this mean that other users need to have the .mo files as well? If yes, would this be the case also for the FMU approach?

Comment: Those are for debugging so you don't need the installation or the libraries. For the exe you will need: 
Model.exe Model_init.xml Model_info.json and the required DLLs. For 1.17.0 you only need libstdc++-6.dll, for 1.18.0 you need way more as we dynamic link the exe.

Comment: When you say "for the generated executables you would need to ship them with the exe and they would need to be in a specific directory on the other machine", you mean that I cannot create a relative path for them? I am actually encountering such issue right now. Basically, I have an external file that is read by the Modelica model, but I cannot figure out how to make it available with a relative path. I tried to put this file in the OpenModelica working directory, but I guess there is a problem here as OpenModelica create sub-folders when running simulations. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What kind of external file do you have? A table? How do you load that? via modelica:// URI or giving an absolute directory?

Comment: It's a .mos file with weather data (I am using the Buildings library). I tried both ways, but it looks like there is no much difference in the path written in the .exe file (I opened the .exe file with a text editor to check)

Comment: I might have solved the issue, but to be sure I need to do more tests. Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Well to be precise, now the dependency to this file disappeared from the .exe file. On one end this is a good sign, but on the other hand it's a bit surprising. I will post here what I find out.

Comment: After some work, I found out that I could generate a .exe file with no dependencies from the .mos file. The only problem was then in the .xml file. However, it was easy to create a relative path and add the .mos file to the folder together with the .exe file. This approach worked.

Comment: Very good! Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 4):

For Dymola:

If you have the appropriate binary export license you can generate a `dymosim.exe` that can be distributed.

Parameter-sweep can be run inside Dymola (the scripts are automatically generated), or from Python etc.

However, running a parameter sweep in that way does not only use `dsin.txt`, but also some additional files. There are two reasons:

- Reduced overhead of starting/stopping dymosim.exe, especially for small models.
- Automatic parallelization.

That part of dymosim is currently not well documented in the manual, but you can run:

- `dymosim -M` Which as default sweeps based on two csv-files (`multIn.csv`, `multOutHeader.csv`) generating a third (`multOut.csv`)
- `dymosim -M -1 mIn.csv -2 mOutH.csv -3 mOut.csv` if you want different file-names
- `dymosim -M -n 45` To generate normal trajectory files, dsres45.mat, dsres46.mat, ...
- `dymosim -h` For help
- `dymosim -s` Normal simulation
- And if you are really bold you can pipe to/from `dymosim.exe` for parameter sweeps

Another possibility is to FMUs instead.

Comment: Do you see any differences in computational time between the two approaches dymosim.exe and FMU? From your answer I can see that the dymosim.exe approach might have some advantages in this regard as it allows to reduce overhead of starting/stopping and automatic parallelization. Are these options also possible if I use the FMU approach? But perhaps I am missing a more general question here: can I simulate an FMU exported by Dymola directly using Python (e.g. using FMPy)? Or do I need an additional software?

Comment: The generated FMI (maybe requiring license) should work in FMPy, and you should be able to reduce the overhead for FMU by only loading the FMU once in the program. (For parallel execution it's probably easiest to load one FMU per thread and run them in parallel.)

Comment: when you say "maybe requiring license" you mean that if I generate an FMU, and give this FMU to, let's say, one of my colleagues, he/she needs to have a licensed Dymola installed?

Comment: No, it should suffice that _you_ have a Dymola license - but I don't recall if that you need some special options.